Decomposition of Completely Bounded Maps
Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $\varphi: A \rightarrow B(H)$ a completely bounded map.

Can we decompose $\varphi$ into a sum of four completely positive operators?

There is a result from Paulsen saying that there exist completely positive $\psi_1,\psi_2 : A \rightarrow B(H)$ such that $\Phi: M_2(A) \rightarrow M_2(B(H))$ defined by
$$
\Phi\left( \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} \psi_1(a) & \varphi(b) \\ \varphi(c)^* & \psi_2(d) \end{bmatrix}
$$
is completely positive. This result is often called the polar form of $\varphi$.
I think that if $\varphi$ can be composed into a sum of four completely bounded maps, then the $\psi_1,\psi_2$ play a big role. I've tried using some combinations with them together with the techniques used to prove the above result but could not arrive at nothing.

If one assumes (without loss of generality) that $\varphi$ is completely contractive, then it is possible to get $\psi_1,\psi_2$ to be unital.
Since $\Phi$ is cp, we have a Stinespring triple $(\pi_0,V_0,K_0)$ for it. In particular $\pi_0:M_2(A)\to B(K_0)$. One can then show that there exist a representation $\pi:A\to B(K)$ and a unitary $W:K_0\to K\oplus K$ such that $\pi_0=W^*\pi^{(2)}\,W$. Then
$$\tag{$*$}
\begin{bmatrix} \psi_1(a) & \varphi(b) \\ \varphi(c)^* & \psi_2(d) \end{bmatrix}
=V_0^*W^*\begin{bmatrix} \pi(a)&\pi(b)\\ \pi(c)&\pi(d)\end{bmatrix}WV_0
$$
If we write $WV_0=\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\ z&w\end{bmatrix}$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1_K&0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1(1_A)&0\\ 0^*&0\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}x^*&z^*\\ y^*&w^*\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}\pi(1_A)&0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\ z&w\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}x^*x&x^*y\\y^*x&y^*y\end{bmatrix},
$$
giving us $x^*x=1$ and $y=0$. With a similar argument on the $2,2$ component we get that $w^*w=1$ and $z=0$. If we denote $V_1=x$, $V_2=y$, the equality $(*)$ now looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \psi_1(a) & \varphi(b) \\ \varphi(c)^* & \psi_2(d) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}V_1^*\pi(a)V_1&V_1^*\pi(b)V_2\\ V_2^*\pi(c)^*V_1&V_2^*\pi(d)V_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Looking at the $1,2$ entries we get
$$
\varphi(a)=V_1^*\pi(a)V_2
$$
for isometries $V_1,V_2$. When $\varphi$ is not cc these isometries will appear multiplied by a positive scalar.
Now one can apply polarization as in David's answer to get
\begin{align}
\varphi(a)&=\frac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k(V_1+i^kV_2)^*\pi(a)(V_1+i^kV_2),
\end{align}
a linear combination of four completely positive maps.

Thank you so much!

Glad I could help! It's a cute argument.

By Stinespring dilation, there exists a Hilbert space $K$, bounded operators $U, V: H \to K$, and a $\ast$-homomorphism $\pi: A \to B(K)$ s.t. $\varphi(x) = U^\ast \pi(x) V$ for all $x \in A$. Observe that, by polarization identity,
$$\varphi(x)
= U^\ast \pi(x) V
= \frac{1}{4}[(U + V)^\ast \pi(x) (U + V) - (U - V)^\ast \pi(x) (U - V) -i (U + iV)^\ast \pi(x) (U + iV) + i (U - iV)^\ast \pi(x) (U - iV)]$$
The four maps on the RHS are all completely positive, which proves the claim.

I wouldn't call the result  "Stinespring". As far as I know, it was proven by Paulsen and Haagerup (independently) in the early 80s.

@MartinArgerami Oh, I know it wasn’t proved by Stinespring. My usage of the name “Stinespring dilation” wasn’t intended to convey credits. It’s just that I usually call all these dilation results, on ucp, cp, cc, and cb maps, “Stinespring dilation”, similar to how basically every result on extending linear functionals is called “Hahn-Banach” despite the original theorem proved by Hahn is only on norm-preserving extensions of continuous linear functionals on subspaces of Banach spaces and the theorem proved by Banach is only on extensions of linear functionals dominated by sublinear functions.

Fair enough :) $ $

(but in the same vein I still wouldn't call Wittstock's Extension Theorem, "Arveson's Extension Theorem" ;) )

@MartinArgerami That’s fair. I suppose one other criteria is whether an alternative well-known name exists. As far as I know, there doesn’t seem to be a widely used alternative name for this dilation result on completely bounded maps.

@DavidGao As always, thank you so much!
